# What's wrong with this F# Code

Tags: f#

```
let compareDiagonal p x y =
    System.Math.Abs((int)(x - (fst p))) <> System.Math.Abs((int)(y  - (snd p)));;

let isAllowed p = function
    | [] -> true
    | list -> List.forall (fun (x, y) -> fst p <> x && snd p <> y && (compareDiagonal p x y))  list;;

let rec solve col list =
    let solCount : int = 0
    match col with
    | col when col < 8 ->
        for row in [0 .. 7] do
            solCount = solCount + if isAllowed (row, col) list then solve (col + 1) ((row, col) :: list) else 0
        solCount        
    | _ -> 1;;

let solCount = solve 0 [];;
solCount;;
```

I am getting the error

```
 solCount = solCount + if isAllowed (row, col) list then (solve (col + 1) ((row, col) :: list)) else 0
------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(335,13): warning FS0020: This expression should have type 'unit', but has type 'bool'. If assigning to a property use the syntax 'obj.Prop <- expr'.
```

Why am I not able to return the number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two related problems.

By default in F# variable are immutable.  If you want a mutable variable, you have to declare it, like this:

```
let mutable solCount : int = 0
```

And then when you assign values to it instead of using `=` you have to use `<-` like this:

```
solCount <- solCount + if isAllowed (row, col) list then solve (col + 1) ((row, col) :: list) else 0
```

A complete example followed.

HOWEVER, this is not the correct functional way to do something like this.  Instead of using a loop to add up values, use a recursive function to return the cumulative value as you go.  Using F# the way functional programs are designed to be used will almost always yield better results, although it takes some getting used to.

Your original example with mutable, not the "functional way":

```
let compareDiagonal p x y =
    System.Math.Abs((int)(x - (fst p))) <> System.Math.Abs((int)(y  - (snd p)));;

let isAllowed p = function
    | [] -> true
    | list -> List.forall (fun (x, y) -> fst p <> x && snd p <> y && (compareDiagonal p x y))  list;;

let rec solve col list =
    let mutable solCount : int = 0
    match col with
    | col when col < 8 ->
        for row in [0 .. 7] do
            solCount <- solCount + if isAllowed (row, col) list then solve (col + 1) ((row, col) :: list) else 0
        solCount        
    | _ -> 1;;

let solCount = solve 0 [];;
solCount;;
```

Comment: Another option is to avoid mutability completely and use continuation passing style or an accumulator to get a tail recursive function

Comment: Another cleaner refactor could include moving the if statement into its own function as a match and using two mutually recursive functions. This way you eliminate embedded logic in the solve function